how can i open multiple pages with firefox in a common new window?
i want to create a shortcut/link on my system that opens the pages aaaa.com, bbbb.com and cccc.com in a common new window with firefox.
i tried it with the start parameters
-new-window aaaa.com -new-tab bbbb.com -new-tab cccc.com

but that did not work when there was already a firefox window running: only aaaa.com was opened in a new window while bbbb.com and cccc.com were opened in the "old" already running window.
but i want aaaa.com, bbbb.com and cccc.com to be opened as tabs within the same common (new) window.

I repeated the issue in the problem using firefox 115.14.0esr (64-bit) under AlmaLinux 8.10.
By trying different options found that starting firefox from the command line and parsing just 3 URLs, rather than using the -new-window or -new-tab options, resulted in one new window opening containing the 3 tabs.
E.g. using:
$ firefox electronics.stackexchange.com superuser.com meta.stackexchange.com

Results in a new firefox window opening with:

